# Fabric React 5 | Rating component allowZeroStars not working

Tags: reactjs, fabric

I am using Fluent UI (Fabric React 5) for spfx development and trying to use Rating component. The component is not recognising allowZeroStarsprop. As per the document this optional prop should be available. Am I missing anything? Or is there any way to make sure there is no rating (star) is selected on page load?
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui?fabricVer=5#/components/rating

[image: allowZeroStars prop is not working]